# Codepen.io: can't do console.log() in d3.csv()

Tags: d3.js, codepen

I am trying to read in `csv` data using `d3` in `codepen.io` and it is not printing me the data, even though it is printing `console.log('hello')` outside the `d3.csv()`:

```
d3.csv("http://learnjsdata.com/data/expenses.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

I added `d3 cdn` of course.
Whats wrong with `codepen.io`? How to make it working?

> In the `debug` mode I see that `codepen.io` does not like that the `expenses.csv` is loaded over `http`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the version of d3 you're using. In d3 v6, they changed from the signature `d3.csv(<file>, <callback>)` to [a promise structure](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/#d3-fetch):

```js
d3.csv("http://learnjsdata.com/data/expenses.csv").then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222672/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-nikita-vlasenko).