# Attempting to work with d3.js and load a .json map file from a web server in Chrome, no errors but data are not loaded

Tags: json, google-chrome, d3.js, webserver

I am new to D3 and JSON, so please bear with me.  I am trying to learn how to display maps and have followed tutorials and example code to no avail (e.g., http://bl.ocks.org/michellechandra/0b2ce4923dc9b5809922, https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/loading-data-from-file-in-d3js).  I eventually would like to bind data to the map, but I am currently stuck on getting the map file to display.  Chrome isn't giving me any errors, it just shows a blank page and an empty console.

I set up my own web server as recommended in *Interactive Data Visualization for the Web* and have saved my working files in the "www" folder as indicated.

I realize a similar type of question has been asked numerous times on this forum but none of the solutions have worked.  I have tried:

- Moving the location of my local map file (out of a subfolder).
- Pointing to the URL of the map file on the server.

Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Applying a projection to SVG paths</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            path {
                stroke: white;
                stroke-width: 0.5px;
                fill: black;
            }   
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        //Sample text to see if anything is working.        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            d3.select("body").append("p").text("Making sure this works.");
        </script>
        
        //Code minimally adapted from Scott Murray's D3 book.
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 300;

            //Define map projection
            var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
                               .translate([w/2, h/2]);

            //Define path generator
            var path = d3.geoPath()
                         .projection(projection)

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Load in GeoJSON data
            d3.json("us-states.json", function(error, data) {
                if (error) return console.error(error);
                console.log(data);
                
                //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                svg.selectAll(path)
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append(path)
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .style("stroke", "#fff")
                   .style("stroke-width", "1")
                   .style("fill", "steelblue");
                }
        
            );
            
        </script>
        
        //Sample text to see if anything is working.
        <script type="text/javascript">
            d3.select("body").append("p").text("And this too.");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Chrome loads the page -- I put sample text in a few places in the code to make sure it was doing *something* and those appear just fine.  However, I asked the data to be logged on the console and nothing is there.

There may be other things wrong with my code, but I suspect this hurdle has something to do with the map file and web server as I can create other svg objects without a problem.  Appreciate your support!

Comment: I see the problem now, it's the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64233815/5015356). You should use `d3.csv(<my-url>).then(function(data) { })`

Comment: Yes, I can see the file contents when I click on the line in the network tab.  I tried the solution you mentioned, only using d3.json rather than d3.csv as I'm trying to read in a json file.  The error I receive is in my svg.data statement - Cannot read property 'features' of undefined.

Comment: What I meant is that you should move the callback function to a `.then()` clause in d3 V6, otherwise the function doesn't get called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223718/discussion-between-jill-brown-and-ruben-helsloot).